# How can I check for invalid input and loop until the input is valid?

Tags: java, list, loops

I am trying to find the smallest number in the list from user input. I need to ask the user how many numbers are going to be in the list (and only accept positive numbers and no letters) and then ask them what the numbers are in the list (accepting only numbers). How can I check for this and keep looping until the numbers are valid?

```
public class SmallestInt {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Initialize a Scanner to read input from the command line
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        int totalIntegers = 1;
        int num = 0;
        int smallest = 0;
        boolean inputValid = false;

        /* Prompt the user and validate their input to ensure they've entered a positive (greater than zero) integer. Discard/ignore any other data.
         */

        while (!inputValid)

        {
            System.out.print("How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer): ");

            try {
                totalIntegers = input.nextInt();
                inputValid = true;

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            }


            /* Read in the candidates for smallest integer
             * Validate this input as well, this time ensuring that the user has provided a valid int (any int will do at this point) and discarding any other data
             */
            for (int ii = 1; ii <= totalIntegers; ii++) {

                // Prompt 
                System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");

                num = input.nextInt();

                if (ii == 1) smallest = num;
                else if (num < smallest) smallest = num;

            }


            // display smallest int

            System.out.println("The smallest number entered was: " + smallest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is it that the typo of leaving `}}` outside of the code block is so common?

Comment: which part of your code is troubling you? or you do not understand? can you please be more specific?

Comment: This has actually been asked many times before on Stack Overflow, and it wouldn't hurt to do a quick search.  The thing you want to learn about is a "do-while loop", which is something that will let you loop over some code until a certain condition is met.

Comment: and as for your problem, I would try leaving the part where you actually use `totalIntegers` outside of the `while` loop where you're trying to read and validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's come up with **an sample** for you so you can follow as your **blueprint**

first, I chose do while loop because you need to ask this question at least once.

he syntax of a **do...while loop** is:

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

> Notice that the Boolean expression appears at the end of the loop, so
>   the statements in the loop execute once before the Boolean is tested.
>
> **If the Boolean expression is true, the flow of control jumps back up
>   to do,** and the statements in the loop execute again. This process
>   repeats until the Boolean expression is false.

Next, you need to see how you can staisfy the boolean_experssion when the input is right, so you can stop looping or if it is wrong, you keep asking the question.

The way that I really like is to use **sentinel value** because using `break` keyword really scares me.

> In programming, a special value that is used to terminate a loop. The
>   sentinel value typically is chosen so as to not be a legitimate data
>   value that the loop will encounter and attempt to perform with. For
>   example, in a loop algorithm that computes non-negative integers, the
>   value "-1" can be set as the sentinel value as the computation will
>   never encounter that value as a legitimate processing output.

so when the input is right you change the value of i, so you can stop the looping or otherwise, showing the message and asking the question again and again till the use hits the right answer.

**Code**:

```
    int i = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (i == 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter number zero plz");
        int result = input.nextInt();
        if(result == 0 ){
            System.out.println("I entered right number");
            i = 1;
        } else
            System.out.println("you entered the wrong number \nplz try again");
    }
```

**output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this is clearly a homework / learning exercise, I won't give you code.  You will learn more if you do the actual coding for yourself.

Once you have fixed the problem with the loop nesting ...

There are three problems with this code:

```
while (!inputValid) {
    System.out.print("How many integers? (Enter a positive integer): ");
    try {
        totalIntegers = input.nextInt();
        inputValid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

First problem is that you are catching the wrong exception.  [Read the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--).

The second problem is that if `nextInt` fails (due to a problem parsing the integer) it puts the scanner's input cursor back to where it was before the call.  And when you call it again (in the next loop iteration) it will attempt to read same "bad" number again, and again, and again, ...

You have to tell the scanner to skip over the invalid line of input so that it can read the user's next attempt.

The third problem is that you don't check that the number you just read is positive!!

Final hint: consider using `while (true)` and a conditional `break`, instead of `while (condition)`.  I think it gives a more elegant solution.

---

@Kick Buttowski's solution deals with the bad input skipping by creating a new `Scanner` on each loop iteration.  Apparently it works ... but I have some doubts<sup>1</sup> that you can rely on this always working.  IMO a better solution would be to use one `Scanner` throughout, and use a `nextLine()` call to read and discard the characters up to and including the end of line.

---

<sup>1 - My main concern is that when you leak a `Scanner` that it might (in some implementations) close the underlying input stream in a finalizer.  If that actually happened, then the application would stop accepting input.  The current implementation does not do this, but this is not clearly specified (AFAIK).</sup>

Comment: @KickButtowski - I don't know of a specific case where it would fail.  I'm just saying that I would *personally* implement it diffferently; i.e. using `readLine` to clear out the bad in put.  That approach has fewer *potential* problems because it doesn't rely on behaviour that the javadoc doesn't specify explicitly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the following info: The second problem is that if nextInt fails (due to a problem parsing the integer) it puts the scanner's input cursor back to where it was before the call. And when you call it again (in the next loop iteration) it will attempt to read same "bad" number again, and again, and again, ...

You have to tell the scanner to skip over the invalid line of input so that it can read the user's next attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop really isn't doing anything for you in terms of stopping the user from advancing. You are able to hit the for loop because it is inside you while loop. Change your while loop and for loop so that the for loop is outside the while loop.

```
while (!inputValid)
{
    System.out.print("How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer): ");

    try {
        totalIntegers = input.nextInt();
        inputValid = true;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
} // End while //

/* Read in the candidates for smallest integer
 * Validate this input as well, this time ensuring that the user has provided a valid int (any int will do at this point) and discarding any other data
 */
for (int ii = 1; ii <= totalIntegers; ii++) {

    // Prompt 
    System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");

    num = input.nextInt();

    if (ii == 1) smallest = num;
    else if (num < smallest) smallest = num;

} // End for //
```